# Understanding the order of async calls and setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, promise, timeout

The code below contains a function (`logger`) that sets a timeout, then consoles an async function, then consoles an element ('c').

The output here is `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

How is it that 'c' waits for the other two to return? The `await` call is inside a console.log, so I thought the 'c' console will go ahead and execute since `await` isn't at the beginning of the console call for 'b'.

In other words, I thought the output should be `'c','a','b'`.

Any enlightenment here would be much appreciated!

```js
async function apiCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('b');
    }, 50);
  });
}

async function logger() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('a'), 10);
  console.log(await apiCall());
  console.log('c');
}

logger();
```

Comment: The arguments of a function are calculated before the function is called. `console.log` is a function, `await apiCall()` is an argument

Comment: The whole point of `await` is to make the asynchronous call seem like it's synchronous. It doesn't matter whether it's a statement or an expression embedded inside a function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `await` inside the `console.log()` call represents a point at which the `logger()` function will return an intermediate promise. Note that the line of code is equivalent to

```
  let p = await apiCall();
  console.log(p);
```

The expression parameters in a function call are evaluated *before* the function is called. Thus, the whole function (`logger()`) has to wait for the promise to resolve before it can proceed to call `console.log()`.